# How to clear a text field in a turbo stream view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I have a text field

```
<%= form.text_field :my_field, class: "...", readonly: true, placeholder: "let's type" %>
```

When I click an element, I wish to remove any value. To do so, I have a `Stimulus` controller as below:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import { get } from "@rails/request.js"

export default class extends Controller {
 ...

  click(event) {
    get("/my/reset", {
      responseKind: "turbo-stream"
    })
  }
}
```

The `My` controller looks like

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def reset
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream
    end
  end
end
```

And, in the turbo stream action (as per Alex's suggestion), I'm trying to replace the field with a new one

```
<%= turbo_stream.replace "my_field" { ... }  %>
```

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access the form object in my .turbo_stream.erb view.

How can I do that?

Comment: these are necessary, but not sufficient... how are you rendering these. What are the headers for the request and the response, exactly what is being sent from the controller. In my experience, Rails turbo is powerful when you get it working, but brittle and will fail mysteriously if some piece of the request/response chain is not exactly correct.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I'm trying to replace the text field, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access the `form` object in my `.turbo_stream.erb` view.

Comment: have you confirmed that Turbo js is actually loaded on the page? Type `Turbo` in the dev tools console of the browser. Is it there?

Comment: Yes, It's loaded. Not sure why that could matter, though. Thanks.

Comment: well something needs to handle the server response and understand that it means 'replace the named element', that's the Turbo js